# Sending results between promises in the promise pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to learn and understand how it works when using "res =>" in the promise pipeline.

The first one **findAllPrices** works great, it has all the data and sends it to findAllPrices which returns even more data...

```
var findAllPrices = function([featuredArray, locationArray, newsArray, hotdealArray, priceArray]) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do a lot of stuff with the data and create priceArray
    resolve({"featured":featuredArray, "location":locationArray, "news":newsArray, "hotdeal": hotdealArray, "prices": priceArray});
})};
```

Then comes the problem, when I come to **return the data** then res is *"undefined"*

How come it cannot send the res from the **findAllPrices** `.then` to the **return the data** `.then`

What am I missing or not understanding correctly?

```
Promise.all([findFeatured(), findLocation(), findNews(), findHotdeal()])
    .then(res => {
        console.log ("findAllPrices: " + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4))
        findAllPrices(res)
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log ("return the data: " + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
        return({error:false,res})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        console.log("getFrontpage ERR: " + err);
        return({error:true,err})
    }
)
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `findAllPrices(res)` to `return findAllPrices(res)`?

Comment: This also means that findAllPrices should return a promise. Also be mindfull that the end result is also an async promise, so you can't return the end result to like a variable directly. You probably want to use a callback to send the end result of your promise chain to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise chain works by returning new promises in the `.then()`:

```js
Promise.all([findFeatured(), findLocation(), findNews(), findHotdeal()])
    .then(res => {
        console.log ("findAllPrices: " + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4))
        return findAllPrices(res) // make this change
    })
    .then(res => {
        // ...
    })
)
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick! - So you ALWAYS return a promise when you are inside a `.then` in a promise pipeline, thats the rule right?

Comment: Yes, the argument of the next `.then()` function is the return value of the previous `.then()` function.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I have seen people use `.then(() => {return(myFunction())}` and `.then(res => {return(myFunction(res))}` and `.then(myFunction)` - is there a difference or what do you recommend to use?

Comment: `.then(myFunction)` is more succinct, so I'd recommend you use that. It does the same thing like `.then(res => {return(myFunction(res))}` or `.then(res => myFunction(res))`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.then(func)` you're chaining the promise.

`.then` will always return a new promise, which will be resolved/rejected according to the return value of `func`.

- If `func` returns a value, the promise returned by `.then` will be resolved with that value
- If `func` have no return, the promise returned by `.then` will be resolved with undefined
- If `func` returns a promise¹, the promise² returned by `.then` will be resolved/rejected according to that promise¹.

So if you want to keep same `res` for the next success calbacks you have to return it.

Answer (score 1):

Better late then never. ;)

```
function doAsyncWork( innput, callback ) {
    Promise.all( [findFeatured(), findLocation(), findNews(), findHotdeal()]) 
        .then(res => {
            // res is the combined results of the the 4 findX() functions
            console.log( "findAllPrices: " + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4) )
            return findAllPrices(res); // This should also return a promise.
        })
        .then(res => {
            // res is the result of the findAllPrices transformation
            console.log( "return the data: " + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4) );
            // done with the entire promise chain
            // We can't return to a non-promise, so if we want to go back to sync code
            // we need to trigger some function that will handle the results.
            // That function can then start working without promises again.
            // If we do want to continue using promises, the orginal return works
            // and then the next step would be `doAsyncWork().then();`
            callback( { error : false, res } );
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            console.log("getFrontpage ERR: " + err);
            callback({error:true,err});
        });
    return true;
}
// Make sure this function also returns a promise
function findAllPrices( res ) {
    // mockup
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) {
        const prices = res.map( item => item.price );
        if ( prices && prices.length ) resolve( prices );
        else reject( { error : true, res } );
    } );
};
```

EDIT:

A mockup of how the controller fits in with the other parts

```
// UI triggered this controller to find all the prices
// Almost fully async
const priceToJSONController = function( event ) {
    // Event should contain a way so the findX functions know which prices they are operating on.
    let getPrices = [
        findFeatured( event ),
        findLocation( event ),
        findNews( event ),
        findHotdeal( event )
    ];
    // Some reference to the JSON module
    // This can be a `require( '/path/to/module' );`
    // Or `$.json()`
    // Or `import createJSON from '/path/to/module'
    // Or even just a reference to another object that is in scope.
    // So this entirely depends on the framework you use.
    // In angular we would set `writeJSONController` as a dependency.
    // In react we would use an import.
    // In this example, we just have the entire json writer in the same scope below.
    // ....
    const writeJSON = writeJSONController;
    // Since all the functions that we use in the 'then' functions
    // We can just write the function name, sicne they all expect a 'res' as the input.
    // this is equivalent to `.then( res => { findAllPrices( res ); } );`
    Promise
        .all( getPrices )
        .then( findAllPrices )
        .then( writeJSON )
        .catch(
            console.error(err);
            console.log("getFrontpage ERR: " + err);
            // Do something with the error
        );
};
// Fully sync
const writeJSONController = function( items ) {
    const formatting = doSomeFormatting( items );
    // insert code that creates JSON file and writes it to some path.
    writeFile( formatting );
};
```

Comment: Shilly that was a great explanation!!.  Question:  What if I make the entire controller as one big over-all promise, and then handle the res/err in the router instead, and let that one return stuff with `res.json`. Would that be a smarter way or is `callback` the best way to go?

Comment: Depends a bit. The errors should generally be handled inside either this controller or by a dedicated error module, since that usually makes it easier to debug. If you need to create a json file with the resulting data, i would use a callback that triggers a module that turns data into a json. The router should only route, not handle errors or create json.

Comment: But to answer your first question, that's how I write my controllers. Each event triggers a chain of promises inside its controller, that will then hand over the results through a callback to either the model to get a state update, a view to get a render, or another controller for further handling. ( a json-maker in this case )

Comment: I tried your example but I get `callback is not a function` This is the top of my controller where I define it `exports.getPrice = function(req, callback){` am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: this is my router:  `router.post('/getPrice', function(req, res) {priceController.getPrice(req, res);} `  and this is a short test controller `exports.getPrice = function(req, callback) { callback( { error:false, date:"HELLO" } ); }`  so why is callback not a function?

Comment: I've updated my post with a NON-working mockup to show how I would fit this controller into the whole of the app. `.then( writeJSONController );` basically replaces the callback in `doAsyncWork( input, callback )` You have to provide a callback obv if you want to use the literal code. Have a look at the module system your framework uses.

Comment: Your second example will not work, I am using controllers which calls other controllers.  But your callback was exactly what I needed. I am trying to get it to work, but without luck.  Perhaps you can take a look at my post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312347/nodejs-how-does-callback-work-with-route-controllers

Comment: Which framework do you use? I'm assuming this is express for the routes and angular? Angular 1 or 2? Hence I write mockups, not implementations.