# NodeJS How does callback work with route/controllers?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand how you guys use callback, and why I keep getting

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Ok this is my router:

```
// getPriceRouter.js
router.post('/getPrice', function(req, res) {
    priceController.getPrice(req, res);
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
// getPriceController.js
exports.getPrice = function(req, callback) {
    callback( { error:false, data:"HELLO" } );
}
```

This keeps giving me the error  *callback is not a function*
(does this has something to do with `export.`?)

I tried it again using suggestions from below...

```
// getPriceRouter.js
router.post('/getPrice', function(req, res) {
    priceController.getPrice(req, function(result) {});
        console.log("getPrice returned:" + result);
        res.json(result);
});
```

But now I get *result is not defined*

If I then instead put a `res=result` then I get *Converting circular structure to JSON*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getPrice` function expects a function (which is a callback) as a second parameter. But you send `res` in your router (which is not a function).

It can be corrected by replacing `res` with a function:

```
// getPriceRouter.js
router.post('/getPrice', function(req, res) {
    priceController.getPrice(req, function(result) {
      // result is now an object with error and data properties.
      // and you can still use req and res
      return res.json(result)
      // It's better to place return since there is no operation left to do with this request.
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried your way, but cant seem to get the result out of the function call.  Let me update my question and show you.

Comment: I updated the question with your suggestions but still have trouble understanding how I read the returned value?

Comment: Got it!  `router.post('/getPrice', function(req, res) {
 priceController.getPrice(req, function(result) {
  res.json(result);
 });
});`  - please update your answer and I will mark it.

Comment: It seems like you forgot to put res.json inside the callback. Glad to you make it work. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a callback function as second argument to `priceController.getPrice`, for instance

```
 priceController.getPrice(req, function(result) {
   if (result.error) { throw result.error; }
   res.send(result.data)
 });
```

Comment: hmm here you make a `function(result)` - so how can it recognize `res.send` ?

Comment: You get the res from the router

Comment: Actually the controller is what makes the res - the req is from the router

Comment: Uh no, you have to use the res from the router to send back data to the user.

Answer (score 0):

A **callback** is a function. Meaning that if you pass an **object** when your code expects a function, it's gonna throw you this error.

Ok so basically, let's say you have the following function:

```
function print(paramToPrint){
    if (paramToPrint !== undefined){
        console.log(paramToPrint)
    } else {
        console.log('Error, paramater is undefined!')
    }
}
```

And this other function:

```
function selectItems(param1, callback){
    var double = param1 * 2;
    callback(double)
}
```

We will now call the function `selectItems` with the function `print` as its **callback** :

```
selectItems(2, print);
```

and the output printed to the console will be `4`. Is this clear to you?

For more infos, I suggest that you check this out, seemed pretty good to me! http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Edit: I did not actually answer your question, but I hope I helped you understand callbacks a little bit :)

Comment: That works fine in normal functions, but not in `exports.getPrice = function`

Answer (score -1):

You are passing req, res objects to your controller method.

The callback in your arguments for 'getPrice' function actually refers to 'res' object which is not a function. In your getPrice method, you're calling this 'res' object with arguments, which is not right, since it is not a function. Hence the error 'callback is not a function'.